# Why can't reset IFS variable?

Tags: reset, ifs

Show the current variable `IFS`:

```
echo $IFS |xxd
00000000: 0a
```

I want to reset `IFS` as default value `\t\n`.

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
echo $IFS |xxd
00000000: 0a
```

Why can't reset IFS variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are resetting `IFS` correctly.  The problem is in your `echo`.  You should use `echo -n "$IFS" | xxd`.

Taking a look at `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> **Word Splitting**
>
> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion ***that did not occur within double quotes*** for word splitting.
>
> The shell treats each character of `IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words on these characters.   ***If  `IFS` is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored***, and any sequence of `IFS` characters  not  at the  beginning or end serves to delimit words.  If `IFS` has a value other than the default, then sequences of the whitespace characters `space` and `tab` are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value of `IFS` (an `IFS` whitespace character).  Any character in `IFS` that is not `IFS` whitespace, along with any adjacent `IFS` whitespace characters, delimits a field.  A sequence of `IFS` whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.  If the value of `IFS` is null, no word splitting occurs.

Since you did not double-quote `IFS`, it goes through the shell's word-splitting logic.  Since `IFS` by definition contains the `IFS` characters within itself, they are ignored by the shell.  Double-quoting prevents this.